# What and how to pass credential using using Python Client Library for gcp compute API

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client

I want to get list of all instances in a project using python google client api `google-api-python-client==1.7.11`
Am trying to connect using method `googleapiclient.discovery.build` this method required credentials as argument

I read documentation but did not get crdential format and which credential it requires

Can anyone explain what credentials and how to pass to make gcp connection

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The credentials that you need are called "Service Account JSON Key File". These are created in the Google Cloud Console under IAM & Admin / Service Accounts. Create a service account and download the key file. In the example below this is `service-account.json`.

Example code that uses a service account:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
sa_file = 'service-account.json'
zone = 'us-central1-a'
project_id = 'my_project_id' # Project ID, not Project Name

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(sa_file, scopes=scopes)

# Create the Cloud Compute Engine service object
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

request = service.instances().list(project=project_id, zone=zone)
while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()

    for instance in response['items']:
        # TODO: Change code below to process each `instance` resource:
        print(instance)

    request = service.instances().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Application default credentials are provided in Google API client libraries automatically. [There](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide#authorization) you can find example using python, also check this documentation [Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

Comment: i have seen this doc but it did not help. I have tried and build oject does not contain relevant attributes that i need 


crad = compute_engine.Credentials()


compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=crad)


compute.instances().list(project='project', zone='us-central1-c').execute()

Comment: getting error
Unable to find the server at metadata.google.internal

Comment: Okay, then try the solution provided by John with [service account] (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts).

Answer (score 0):

According to GCP most recent [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production):

> we recommend you use Google Cloud Client Libraries for your
> application. Google Cloud Client Libraries use a library called
> Application Default Credentials (ADC) to automatically find your
> service account credentials

In case you still want to set it manaully, you could, first create a service account and give all necessary permissions:

```sh
# A name for the service account you are about to create:
export SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME=your-service-account-name

# Create service account:
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME} --display-name="Service Account for ai-platform-samples repo"

# Grant the required roles:
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} --member serviceAccount:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME}@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/ml.developer
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} --member serviceAccount:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME}@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/storage.objectAdmin

# Download the service account key and store it in a file specified by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} --iam-account ${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME}@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Once it's done check whether the ADC path has been set properly by checking:

```sh
echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

Having set the ADC path, you don't need to import from code the service access key, which undesirable, so the code looks as follows:

```py
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(<API>, <version>,cache_discovery=False)
```