# I want to create google sheet from python using Pycharm but its not working

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, pycharm, google-drive-api

I was try to create google sheet using python in Pycharm but I try very had didn't out bugs.
here I submit my full code and show my error result.

```
    # [START sheets_create]
from __future__ import print_function

import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


def create(title):
    """
    Creates the Sheet the user has access to.
    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.\n"
        """
    creds = 'conof.json'
    # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        spreadsheet = {
            'properties': {
                'title': title
            }
        }
        spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet,
                                                    fields='spreadsheetId') \
            .execute()
        print(f"Spreadsheet ID: {(spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId'))}")
        return spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Pass: title
    create("mysheet1")
    # [END sheets_create]
```

This is default code I found from google sheet development [site](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create#python) I just added here my json file from google cloud console generated. I was hard to manage to solve library error's. I am using windows platform.

And my error's

```
    C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/createShee/mumu.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\mumu.py", line 37, in <module>
    create("mysheet1")
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\mumu.py", line 19, in create
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 298, in build
    service = build_from_document(
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 604, in build_from_document
    http = _auth.authorized_http(credentials)
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_auth.py", line 124, in authorized_http
    return credentials.authorize(build_http())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'authorize'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me to solve this project.

Comment: your credentials are a string referring to a file that has credentials. you need to load that file and create a google.auth.credentials.Credentials object from them. https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build  https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.auth.credentials.html

Comment: @smcrowley you are telling me about this line of code: service = 
build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
.............?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **credential** parameter of `build()` method can only accept the following objects:

> credentials: oauth2client.Credentials or
> google.auth.credentials.Credentials, credentials to be used for
> authentication.

An easy way to create a credential object is to use the authentication in the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) of **Google Sheets API**.

Just follow the Quickstart guide, change the scope to `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'` and replace the `try-except` block with the try-except block in the [Create a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create#python).

### Your code should look like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

def create(title):
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        spreadsheet = {
            'properties': {
                'title': title
            }
        }
        spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet,
                                                    fields='spreadsheetId') \
            .execute()
        print(f"Spreadsheet ID: {(spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId'))}")
        return spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create("mysheet1")
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Notes:** *Make sure to install the necessary package included in the Quickstart guide, download the credential json file, save it in the same directory as your script and rename it to credentials.json*

### Reference:

- [Module discovery](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html)

Comment: Wait Sir.... I will try this now.....

Comment: Didn't understand ???
what is token.json and how to generate that.... and credentials.json is my conof.json

Comment: in your code, if token not found then it will write the token, but I have my json file.
So what to writh now? or where I attach my json file.

Comment: This are the error come

Comment: C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/createShee/mumu.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\mumu.py", line 51, in <module>
    create("mysheet1")
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\mumu.py", line 26, in create
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(

Comment: File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\venv\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 207, in from_client_secrets_file
    return cls.from_client_config(client_config, scopes=scopes, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\venv\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 165, in from_client_config
    raise ValueError("Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.")
ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: OK............... found the problem....
It was the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs setup, I didn't setup last night. I share some photo link so that you can understand, 
Your code is 100% working sir,,,,,,,,,,,, Thank you so much.........
 1. https://ibb.co/GWjNm2K
2. https://ibb.co/WfkpsvQ
3. https://ibb.co/k9bqJ89

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `creds = 'conof.json'` with

```py
credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('conof.json)
```

and adding the import as necessary.

You are currently passing a string to the `credentials` parameter in `build`; however, `build` expects you to pass a specific type of credentials object to it.  You can obtain this credential object from a JSON file using the line of code above.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589526/what-and-how-to-pass-credential-using-using-python-client-library-for-gcp-comput) for more detail.

Comment: Please wait I am trying

Comment: Sir my 5 errors are gone Just have 1 error now

Comment: File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\mumu.py", line 16
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('conof.json)
                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: This is my new error now........? What to do?

Comment: Ohh.......... sorry I was missed ' this now it has 2 errors

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\mumu.py", line 38, in <module>
    create("mysheet1")
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\mumu.py", line 16, in create
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('conof.json')
AttributeError: module 'google.oauth2' has no attribute 'credentials'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I debug my code... I found this
1 = {AttributeError} module 'google.oauth2' has no attribute 'credentials'

 args = {tuple: 1} module 'google.oauth2' has no attribute 'credentials'
 
  0 = {str} "module 'google.oauth2' has no attribute 'credentials'"
  
  __len__ = {int} 1

Comment: C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/pc/PycharmProjects/createShee/mumu.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\mumu.py", line 38, in <module>
    create("mysheet1")
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\createShee\mumu.py", line 16, in create
    cred = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('conof.json')
AttributeError: module 'google.oauth2' has no attribute 'credentials'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @AsifUzZaman Perhaps try replacing the line I gave you with `credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('service-account.json')` and importing `Credentials` with `from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials`